# filter the value of input text in php ( url address )

Tags: php, regex

I've a form which has one field which is the url address.
I want to filter the value before insert it in database.
I look at three cases:

- Enter: mywebsite.com
- Enter: www.mywebsite.com
- Enter: http://www.mywebsite.com

I'd like to get always the last case.
Thanks, Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a regex for this; simple string-matching will do:

```
$urls = array(
    'mywebsite.com',
    'www.mywebsite.com',
    'http://www.mywebsite.com'
);
$newurls = array();
foreach ($urls as $url) {
    if (substr($url, 0, 11) == 'http://www.') {
        $newurls[] = $url;
    } elseif (substr($url, 0, 4) == 'www.') {
        $newurls[] = 'http://' . $url;
    } else {
        $newurls[] = 'http://www.' . $url;
    }
}
var_dump($newurls);
```

This will output:

```
array(3) {
  [0] =>
  string(24) "http://www.mywebsite.com"
  [1] =>
  string(24) "http://www.mywebsite.com"
  [2] =>
  string(24) "http://www.mywebsite.com"
}
```

While this does what you ask, it's probably not a good idea to assume that URLs always start with www, or even http.

Answer (score 2):

Try PHP's native function [filter_var](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.filter-var.php):

```
filter_var('http://example.com', FILTER_VALIDATE_URL);
```

This example:

```
    $urls = array(
        'mywebsite.com',
        'www.mywebsite.com',
        'http://www.mywebsite.com'
    );
    echo filter_var($urls[0], FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) ? '+' : '-';
    echo filter_var($urls[1], FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) ? '+' : '-';
    echo filter_var($urls[2], FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) ? '+' : '-';
```

Outputs:

```
--+
```

Comment: Hi, thanks you for your answer, but it doesn't work, because I need always obtain http://www.mywebsite.com

Comment: And filter_var seems to returns false if the filter fails, or the same string if the filter works fine.